# Let $I$ be the set of polynomials $f(x)$ for with $f(2) = f'(2) = f''(2) = 0$. Prove this set forms an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

(a) Let $I \subset \mathbb {R}[x]$ be the set of polynomials $f(x)$ for with $f(2) = f'(2) = f''(2) = 0$. Prove that this set forms an ideal, and find a polynomial $g(x)$ for which $I = g(x)R[x]$

(b) Let $J \subset \mathbb {R}[x]$ be the set of polynomials $f(x)$ for which $f(2) = f'(3) = 0$. Show that $J$ is not an ideal.

I have no idea about how to approach this problem, the only thing I sure is $f(x) = (x-2)g(x)$, but I don't know how to solve it. Please help me to do this! Thank you!

Comment: Hint: (a) First check that this set is nonempty and that it is closed under subtraction.  Now, for any $h(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $f(x)\in I$ take derivatives of $h(x)f(x)$ at $2$.  Finally, find the simplest nonzero $g(x)\in I$ that satisfies the conditions; that should be the correct $g(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for the first part of (a): try directly checking the conditions for being an ideal.  For instance, suppose that you know the polynomial $p(x)$ is in $I$.  Then how would you show that $p(x)q(x)$ is in $I$?  Let $r(x)=p(x)q(x)$; what do you know about $r(2)$?  What do you know about $r'(x)$ in general, and how does that let you calculate $r'(2)$?

Hint for the second part of (a): as suggested by Bernard's answer, the Taylor series provides a big hint here: if $p(x)\in I$, then you know that $p(x)$ has a *triple root* at $2$, and thus that it's divisible by $(x-2)^3$.  Contrariwise, if $p(x)$ is divisible by $(x-2)^3$ - i.e., if $p(x)=(x-2)^3q(x)$ - then can you show that $p(x)$ is in $I$?

Hint for (b): consider your answer for the first part of (a).  What piece of that breaks down when you're calculating $p(x)$ and $p'(x)$ at different points?  Can you try and use that to find polynomials $p, q$ so that $p(x)\in J$ but $p(x)q(x)$ isn't?

Answer (score 1):

Use Taylor's expansion at $x=2$, which is a *exact* formula for polynomials. It follows from the hypotheses that this expansion begins with $\dfrac{f'''(2)}6(x-2)^3$ In other words, the ideal is generated by $(x-2)^3$.